# Is it a good idea to deploy a GraphQL server on Google Cloud Functions or AWS Lambda? Otherwise what are the alternatives?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, graphql, google-cloud-functions

This morning, I asked me "What are the different tech stacks to deploy a GraphQL server in the cloud (AWS, GCP, etc.)?

And after some research, I found some tutorials which are using AWS Lambda. But is it a good idea to deploy a GraphQL server on Google Cloud Functions or AWS Lambda? Otherwise what are the alternatives?

Some tutorials that I have found which are using AWS Lambda :

- https://serverless.com/blog/running-scalable-reliable-graphql-endpoint-with-serverless/
- https://hackernoon.com/create-a-serverless-graphql-server-using-express-apollo-server-and-aws-lambda-c3850a2092b5
- https://medium.com/@cody.taft/serverless-graphql-with-aws-f7b6da9d2162

Comment: please share some of the tutorials you looked at. maybe also some code example(s).

Comment: Done, I have modified my post.

Comment: One of the things to consider is a volume of API calls to your GraphQL server. If the load will be infrequent or infrequent and spiky, serverless architecture could be correct stack. If a volume is steady, go with traditional server